# Most "efficient" way to max out CPU/GPU in iOS?

Tags: ios, max, gpu, cpu, overheating

This may sound like a bizarre question, but what's the best way to quickly max out an iPhone's CPU and/or GPU (and overheat the phone)? I've tried running a ton of threads each getting current location and making some network calls, but this still doesn't seem to overheat the phone enough.

Any idea how I can do this (bizarre) task fastest?

Comment: Check out that: https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/pocket-heat/id348529925?mt=8 - or if you do it on your own: You could search for prime numbers.

Comment: You can try my GPU test case that will ma out the alpha composition logic: https://github.com/mdejong/TreesMaxComp